# Laravel 8 PHPUnit Failed Test -- Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\FileNotFoundException : File does not exist at path

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

When running the test below, I get an error at the line `$this->assertTrue(File::exists(database_path('migrations/'.$filename)));`.  My model is being created and the migration file is being created, but I don't think the `$filename` function is running properly because the migration file being created is named `2021_10_28_165227_create_tests_table.php` but the `assert` checks are looking for migration file `2021_10_28_045227_create_tests_table.php`. As you can see `$now->format('h')` part of the filename is different from what is created than what is being verified.

A separate variable that may or may not be an issue is I am using Laravel Valet, which might be a reason the hour, seconds and minutes are not synced to my local time.

```
...
class TenantScopeTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase, WithFaker;
    
    public function a_model_has_a_tenant_id_on_the_migration()
    {
        $now = Carbon::now();
        $this->artisan('make:model Test -m');

        // find the migration file and check it has a tenant_id on it
        $filename = $now->year . '_' . $now->format('m') . '_' . $now->format('d') . '_' . $now->format('h')
            . $now->format('i') . $now->format('s') .
            '_create_tests_table.php';
        $this->assertTrue(File::exists(database_path('migrations/'.$filename)));
        $this->assertStringContainsString('$table->unsignedBigInteger(\'tenant_id\')->index();',
            File::get(database_path('migrations/'.$filename)));
        // clean up
        File::delete(database_path('migrations/'.$filename));
        File::delete(app_path('Models/Test.php'));
    }
...
```

Comment: So selecting a different timezone when using Carbon::now would fix your issue?

Comment: Awesome! That worked.  Submit as answer and I'll accept.  Thank you.

Comment: Good to know! Thanks

Comment: Your test makes no sense at all, you are testing if `make:model` (a native framework console command) works... you never have to test the framework, but your own code, so is this `make:model` your replacement or is it the native command ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe selecting a different timezone when using Carbon::now() would fix your issue